# Winforms Invalidate doesn't fire up OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint, invalidation

I'm trying to move a form smoothly using code given on question [How to smoothly animate Windows Forms location with different speeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967968/how-to-smoothly-animate-windows-forms-location-with-different-speeds)

But for some reason my this.Invalidate() call will never fire up the OnPaint event. Is there some configuration that's required on the form for this to be possible?

**Edit:**

Threading is involved, as it runs in a backgroundworker with it's own messageloop. Here's the code :

```
public class PopupWorker
{
    public event PopupRelocateEventHandler RelocateEvent;

    private BackgroundWorker worker;
    private MyPopup popupForm;

    public PopupWorker()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        popupForm = PopupCreator.CreatePopup("Title", "BodyText");
        this.RelocateEvent += popupForm.OnRelocate;
        popupForm.CustomShow();
        Application.Run();
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void PopupRelocate(object sender, Point newLocation)
    {
        if (popupForm.InvokeRequired)
            popupForm.Invoke(new PopupRelocateEventHandler(PopupRelocate), new object[] {sender, newLocation});
        else
            RelocateEvent(this, newLocation);
    }
}
```

Form :

```
public void OnRelocate(object sender, Point newLocation)
{
    targetLocation = newLocation;
    this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (Location.Y != targetLocation.Y)
    {
        Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + 10);
        if (Location.Y > targetLocation.Y)
            Location = targetLocation;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see some of your code please?

Comment: are you calling it within a thread?

Answer (score 3):

The code in the linked question uses Application.DoEvents, that is the key part for letting OnPaint happen.
Without that, you could use Form.Refresh() instead of Invalidate.

For more details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952906/how-do-i-call-paint-event/952964#952964).

#### Edit:

Your code does show some problems, but it is not complete. Let's start with the basics, in order to make a Form move all you need is to enable a Timer and this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 2, this.Location.Y + 1);
}
```

Comment: Refresh is usually a bad idea as it forces a paint. This means his UI animations could peg the CPU.

Comment: @Frank: The only difference is forcing vs request. Both repaint.

Comment: Frank, the OP wants to Move and RePaint. That taxes the CPU, not the method how.

Comment: Timer was my first strategy, and it did work. But the movement wasn't very smooth and I didn't want to create a timer that would tick every 1 milliseconds.