# split container forms in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a splitcontainer and a form in that.when i click one button in a form, another form which is continuation of former appears. now i want to achieve sliding effect when one disappears and other appears instead of just closing and opening.The both forms are housed in right panel of splitcontainer.how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Question title is wrong as you actually want to know how to animate windows forms mostly.

If you search for animation winforms you will find several articles from which to get some ideas, see this for example: [How to smoothly animate Windows Forms location with different speeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967968/how-to-smoothly-animate-windows-forms-location-with-different-speeds)